# Azure VM and VN connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-connect

I start learning Azure. Can somebody help me? How to connect 2 VMs in Virtual Network?

I have : 
 - 2 VM and 1 RG

- Vnet, where I cant, connect 2 VM

*Tell me how I can do that* 
Thanks)

ps my English is bad I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

We have lots of information around Virtual Networks in Azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quick-create-portal

Whenever you create a new VM in Azure you will be required to allocate it to a new Vnet or an existing one. This can be done many ways the simplest if you are just learning Azure would be the portal.

I would suggest you follow some of our quick start guides for creating VMs and take note of the steps where you allocate a Virtual Network

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal

If you are looking to change the Virtual Network associated with a VM that was already created that is not supported. You will need to delete the VM and rebuild it allocating to the new Virtual Network